# Computer with Ubuntu: how to add a second Win10 disk and do dual booting

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have never needed dual-booting, and know zip about it. My knowledge is limited to "zapping windows, install Ubuntu".
Unfortunately, my wife needs x-plane with VR with HTC VIVE, which doesn't yet run properly in Ubuntu.
What's the easiest way to:

- Add a second disk with Windows 10 in it (I can easily do this as I have a friend with a computer shop)
- Add Windows as a boot possibility

...?
So:

- Do I get Windows going first, and then re-add Ubuntu's HD?
- Do I need to re-run grub? Will it pick up the new partition?
- Do I need a small partition to allow Windows to boot?
- Do I need to disable whatever weirdness there is in terms of secure boot, uefi stuff, etc? (I have no idea what these are and how they will create trouble)

Help... I just can't face hours of me trying to get the two drives to boot. Any hints/advice will be most welcome!

Comment: If you have UEFI *and* Ubuntu installed that way, it should be quite easy. Otherwise, either you reinstall both in UEFI mode or Windows will end up replacing Grub and it needs to be reinstalled from a live session.

Comment: *"I have never needed dual-booting, and know zip about it."*  If that's the case, I would recommend against this configuration.  Honestly, we see a **lot** of questions within the Super User community from people who are dual-booting between Windows and Linux, but have encountered a wide variety of problems in the aftermath.  It would probably be much easier (and more stable) to install Windows 10 on the physical machine, then utilize a free hypervisor like VirtualBox or Hyper-V to install Ubuntu.